# Capturing net.Listener passed to http.Server.Serve

Tags: go, wrapper, httpserver

I'd like to extend the `http.Server` functionality by performing a graceful shutdown and some other gadgets that I would share across my HTTP services. Currently my code says more or less:

```
type MyServer struct {
    server *http.Server
    // ...
}

func (s *MyServer) ListenAndServe() {
    // Create listener and pass to s.server.Serve()
}
```

This works *great*, but requires exposing all necessary methods and variables of `http.Server` manually.

Wrapping most of the methods wouldn't be a big problem, but I can't find a sensible way to expose access to `http.Server.ListenAndServeTLS` without actually copying implementation from [the source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?s=54154:54222#L1813). The last line in the method says `srv.Serve(tlsListener)` and I'd love to provide my own `Serve` method, so modification of `net.Listener` is possible before passing it to `http.Server.Serve`.

I started to pencil my wrapper by putting simply:

```
type MyServer struct {
    http.Server
}

func (s *MyServer) Serve(l net.Listener) {
    // Wrap l with MyListener, pass to s.Server.Serve()
}
```

but *obviously* neither `http.ListenAndServe` nor `http.ListenAndServeTLS` would start using my implementation of `Serve`. And I'd like to ask them to... Is there any way I can tackle the problem or does the design of `http.Server` effectively prevent me from solving this?

Hacks welcome: even if I don't use them in production, I'll gain some knowledge.

Comment: Don't try to be clever, you want a graceful `net.Listener`, so supply a `net.Listener`. You don't need to care who uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The `http.ListenAndServe*` methods will work on the embedded type. The other way around works:

```
type MyServer struct {
  http.Server
  // ...
}

func (s *MyServer) ListenAndServe() error {
  // create listener
  // s.Server.Serve(s.listener)
}

func (s *MyServer) ListenAndServeTLS() error {
  // create listener
  // s.Server.Serve(s.tlsListener)
}
```

Comment: If I call `MyServer.ListenAndServeTLS` then `http.Server.Serve` will be used and not my provided implementation. I want to capture `net.Listener` created in `ListenAndServeTLS`.

Comment: Then implement also the `ListenAndServeTLS()` analogous to the `ListenAndServe()` in my example. Upated the example :)

Comment: This is **exactly** my question: I don't want to implement it, because it's non-trivial. I can copy the implementation from [original http implementation](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?s=54154:54222#L1813), but wondering if this can be avoided.